# Problem with GMaps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm getting an error after calling set center function from google maps api.

```
this.Pg is undefined
l.rz=function(a){if(this.Nb)return this.Pg.apply(this.Nb,a)};
```

I don't know what is the reason. Maybe someone had noticed similar issue? thx

Comment: You're probably missing some initialization. Can you post your JavaScript code?

Comment: @beetstra is right; this needs more context.

Answer (score 4):

```
var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
var lng = document.getElementById("lng").value;

event.LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); 

center = event.LatLng;
     var myOptions = {
     zoom:9,// zoon
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 
     center: center
                }
```

`lat` and `lng` variables are coming from a field is so tailor your html code.

or..

```
 var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); 
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom:9,// zoon
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 
                    center: center

                }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use proper parameter and 
like

```
  map.setCenter(new GLatlang(34.555,68.999), 18);
```

and please close thread after getting solution.